# Ubuntu server extract O.S Image

Tags: ubuntu, backup, ubuntu-server

I have a server running on Ubuntu server LTS 14.04 and I need to do an entire copy of the operating system including apps, files, databases, everything. I've read the most straightforward way to do this is make an O.S image backup but I didn't find a practical tutorial about how to do this and how to restore this image in any server or virtual server.

Answer (score 0):

You likely found your answer by now doing some more research but I had the same question and found the following useful answers:

- https://serverfault.com/a/128617/362650. This one is especially useful if you happen to need to set back your virtualized server to your physical machine or need to copy/clone your virtual machine. It utilizes `dd` to create disk images.
- https://serverfault.com/a/324443/362650[2](https://serverfault.com/a/324443/362650). This additionally shows how to convert the disk image to a VirtualBox virtual disk image using `qemu-img convert -O vdi`.

You could also use tools like **Mondorescue** or **CloneZilla** for making the images and the VirtualBox command line tool `VBoxManage convertfromraw` for converting the disk image to an virtual disk image https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#idm4974.